# Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'Array''

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I am getting the "Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'Array''" for the below code.. Aim is to create a calculator template and then call these methods to run the various operations. 
Errors are coming in the areas marked //HERE.. Please help. I am a newbie when it comes to c# coding, so, all help is appreciated and I would like it if someone could explain me the issue too. Thanks

```
private static Array NumberFeedLengthDecider()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter how many numbers that you would like to add.");
    int i = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    int[] numbers = new int[i];

    return numbers;
}
private static int NumberFeed(Array numbers)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter the numbers one by one, each followed by the 'Enter' key.");
    int i = numbers.Length;

    for (int counter = 0; counter < i; counter++)
    {
        int temp = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        numbers[counter] = temp; //HERE
    }
    return i;
}
private static void NumberDisplay(Array numbers)
{
    Console.WriteLine("The numbers you have entered are: ");
    int i = (numbers.Length);

    for (int x = 0; x < i; x++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(numbers[x]); //HERE
    }
}
```

Basically, I want to create a method for deciding the number of numbers the operations are to be run on which is the first one (numberFeedLengthDecider), then another method to feed the numbers into that array (NumberFeed), and then another method to display that group of numbers (NumberDisplay). but for some reason, I can't seem to get it to work

Answer (score 6):

`Array` is the base class for arrays, its elements aren't "strongly typed"; you can put any object in it.

Since you seem to be dealing with `int` elements only, you should be using `int[]` where you now use `Array`. You can then access elements with the [] indexing, and you ensure that each element is an `int` to boot.

Comment: I'm sorry but I didnt understand.. Sorry

Comment: Instead of `private static int NumberFeed(Array numbers)`, use `private static int NumberFeed(int[] numbers)`. Just replace `Array` with `int[]` everywhere. No need to be sorry, you're learning and I might not be the best teacher!

Comment: Ohh. Got it. So, for example, if I was using characters, then I would be using char[] correct??

Comment: So, to call them, I would need to use this NumberFeedLengthDecider(); NumberFeed(); NumberDisplay(); Correct?

Comment: Sorry I was out all day. Yes that seems to be the correct order. You'd need to keep the return value of the first method, and supply it to the rest: `int[] array = NumberFeedLengthDecider();`, `NumberFeed(array);` and `NumberDisplay(array);`.

Answer (score 0):

You could rewrite this code with something like this
Check the IEnumerable interface and List class
This code is cleaner and removes NumberFeedLengthDecider method, this method is making noise in the code. When you don't know how many inputs you will have use List class, it uses more memory than classic array, but gets the job done in situations like this. For better conversions check out TryParse and Parse method (ex. int.TryParse() and int.Parse()) and work more with exception handling.

```
public List<int> Insert() 
{
      //Output here something to the console

      List<int> numbers  = new List<int>();

      while(true) 
      {
            var input = Console.ReadLine();
            if(input.ToLower() == "done") break;
            try 
            {

                 numbers.Add(Convert.Int32(input));
            }
            catch(FormatException e)
            {
                  Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
     }
     return numbers;

}

public void Print(IEnumerable<int> numbers)
{
     foreach(var num in numbers) 
     {
          Console.WriteLine(num);
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help guys! Really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Use "SetValue".  Example:

```
Array? arr = Array.CreateInstance(arrayType, source.Count);
for (int i = 0; i < source.Count; i++)
{
   arr.SetValue(source[i], i);
}
```

Or, in your case:

```
for (int counter = 0; counter < i; counter++)
{
    int temp = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    numbers.SetValue[counter] = temp;
    
   // to read back...
   Console.WriteLine(arr.GetValue(counter));
}
```