# Fastest way to index into basetype `Array`

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm getting the error: "[Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'Array''](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51118643/cannot-apply-indexing-with-to-an-expression-of-type-array)" from the following code:

```
ss.Evaluate(0, 0, 1, 0)[1]
```

where `Evaluate()` is a method returning [an Array (the base type)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array?view=netframework-4.7.2)

[image: <code>Evaluate</code> signature]

I need to grab only the 2nd item from the array so I don't want to waste time casting the whole thing (which does work but it's obnoxious):

```
List<ComPoint> cps = ss.Evaluate(0, 0, 1, 0).Cast<ComPoint>().ToList();
```

Is there a better way? Getting the folks who wrote the function to change it isn't an option. Or maybe the whole array isn't actually cast with a call to `Cast`? Maybe it's lazy casting so there is no speed hit?

Comment: [`.GetValue(1)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.getvalue?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Array_GetValue_System_Int32_)?

Comment: `((IList)result)[1]` or `((ComPoint[])result)[1]` (assuming that's the actual type) or `result.GetValue(1)`

Comment: "Maybe it's lazy casting so there is no speed hit?" Why not simpy try it out by **measuring**? I doubt the casting would hurt you much.

Comment: `Enumerable.Cast<T>` is not "lazy" (it doesn't just return your *origina*l array with the right type) It will iterate over each object in the source and do a direct cast. https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.core/system/linq/Enumerable.cs,152b93d25e224365,references

Comment: Array is the abstract base types of any arrays in C#.  Could be jagged, could be a vector, could be single-dimensional, could be multi-dimensional.  [Indexing] can't work.  This quacks like a COM interop method, could even be a non-conforming array whose lower index is not 0.  So you might need Array.GetLowerBound(), definitely Array.GetValue() and an assert on Array.Rank

Comment: @HansPassant It *is* a COM interop method *and* the lower index is 1. Are you spying on me?

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 `(IList)` works. `(ComPoint[]) does not.

Comment: @GSerg How did I miss that? `GetValue(1)` is the obvious simple fast answer and it works